# Constructing Timestamp object in EST

Tags: java

I have a database table with column which is of type TIMESTAMP(6). I want to always store timestamp in EST time in that column. Can anyone help how to construct a timestamp object with EST time in it?

Comment: Consider creating your database column with a type such as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` — that lets the database and JDBC driver take care of timezone issues automatically, so you can just treat your timestamps as timezone-independent absolute points in time.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we use PreparedStatement#setTimestamp(int paramIndex, Timestamp ts) to store a timestamp in the DB. It makes use of 'java.util.Date' on Java side and java.sql.Timestamp on JDBC side to do so. This call will result in your JDBC driver to calculate the time in the timezone of the JVM. However, storing of timestamp along with information of timezone is upto the database. If the column does not store information of the timezone then the application accessing it will need to handle that.

Now if you want to store timestamp in a timezone that is different from your JVM TZ, then you should consider using:  `PreparedStatement#setTimestamp(int paramIndex, Timestamp ts, Calendar cal)`

Give this a try and let me know if it works.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
stmt.setTimestamp(10, ts, cal);
```